# How to figure out #define values in a hardware in designing library

Tags: c++, c, controller, embedded

Newbie question for library designers, how to determine #define values (in this case MPU6050.h)?  I can't wrap my head where these values came from. (0x68, 0x00, etc)

```
#define MPU6050_ADDRESS_AD0_LOW     0x68 // address pin low (GND), default for InvenSense evaluation board
#define MPU6050_ADDRESS_AD0_HIGH    0x69 // address pin high (VCC)
#define MPU6050_DEFAULT_ADDRESS     MPU6050_ADDRESS_AD0_LOW

#define MPU6050_RA_XG_OFFS_TC       0x00 //[7] PWR_MODE, [6:1] XG_OFFS_TC, [0] OTP_BNK_VLD
#define MPU6050_RA_YG_OFFS_TC       0x01 //[7] PWR_MODE, [6:1] YG_OFFS_TC, [0] OTP_BNK_VLD
#define MPU6050_RA_ZG_OFFS_TC       0x02 //[7] PWR_MODE, [6:1] ZG_OFFS_TC, [0] OTP_BNK_VLD
#define MPU6050_RA_X_FINE_GAIN      0x03 //[7:0] X_FINE_GAIN
#define MPU6050_RA_Y_FINE_GAIN      0x04 //[7:0] Y_FINE_GAIN
#define MPU6050_RA_Z_FINE_GAIN      0x05 //[7:0] Z_FINE_GAIN
#define MPU6050_RA_XA_OFFS_H        0x06 //[15:0] XA_OFFS
#define MPU6050_RA_XA_OFFS_L_TC     0x07
#define MPU6050_RA_YA_OFFS_H        0x08 //[15:0] YA_OFFS
#define MPU6050_RA_YA_OFFS_L_TC     0x09
#define MPU6050_RA_ZA_OFFS_H        0x0A //[15:0] ZA_OFFS
```

Comment: They probably came from the datasheet for the chip you are using. Why do you need to find the source?

Comment: Thank you for the input Emmanuel, just for research purposes, trying to figure out how things work.  Maybe someday I will write my own - who knows? :)  I looked at the MPU6050 data sheet I can't seem to find these values.  What sourcery is this?

Comment: They must come from the chip manufacturer so you should be able to find them somewhere. Sorry, I don't know about that specific chip, so I can't point you to the correct source.

Comment: The information will be somewhere in either the data sheet or a more detailed manual. It comes from the designers of the hardware.  There is no other way to find out unless someone else has already done the work for you.

Comment: thanks, everyone for giving me guidance I think I found it. https://43zrtwysvxb2gf29r5o0athu-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most code for embedded controllers have a lot of these defines. Each define either represents a register base address of an offset from that base. Then you could also have bit-masks that are used to access specific bits inside on an address. E.g.

```
#define MEMORYADD_OUTPUTENABLED (1<<5)
```

You seem to be using the MPU-6050 3-axis accelerometer. If you look in the [datasheet](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/MPU6050-DataSheet.pdf) for that device, they mention the "MPU-6000/MPU-6050 Register Map and Register Descriptions". Looking in [that document](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf) you can find the register map, which looks like this:

[image]

See the connection?

These defines help you write readable interfacing code with your component.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to google it.  I was about to answer my own question but I saw your answer already.  I also found it here based on the comments previously given by the community.  Stay awesome dear sir!  https://43zrtwysvxb2gf29r5o0athu-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf